# Preserve variable name while destructuring in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring, object-destructuring

Is it possible to use both variable name and destructuring in a **single instruction** in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Like this:

```js
function stopTheCar(car & { speed } : Car) {
  if (speed > 10) car.stop()
}
```

The best closest approach I know is to use destructuring in a separate instruction:

```js
function stopTheCar(car : Car) {
  const { speed } = car

  if (speed > 10) car.stop()
}
```

But this introduce some limitations. In case of arrow functions blocks are necessary, which might be inconvenient.
Like this:

```js
cars.forEach(rect => {
  const { left, top } = rect

  return {
    left,
    top,
    intersection : rect.intersect(anotherRect),
  }
})
```

Instead of this:

```js
cars.forEach(rect & { left, top } => ({
  left,
  top,
  intersection : rect.intersect(anotherRect),
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *good* way. The closest you can get, similar to your first code block, is by using another argument (which is not passed) that defaults to the first:

```
type Car = {
    speed: number;
    stop: () => void;
}
function stopTheCar(car: Car, { speed } = car) {
    if (speed > 10) car.stop()
  }
```

But I wouldn't recommend that - it'd be very confusing for consumers of the function to see a possible two arguments when you really only want one to be passed.

Destructuring in the first line of the function instead is the better way, even if it takes a bit of boilerplate.